# How to compute the fitted values of an MA(1) model manually?

Tags: time-series, arima, moving-average-model

I'd like to graph in Excel the fitted values of: [image: this]
MA(1) model I estimated using Eviews.
I can't figure how to use the MA estimated coefficient to calculate the model output. Is there any straighforward way of doing this like in AR models?
Other questions and answers regading this subject seem to be only related to model estimation and not how to actually compute the output.

Comment: Given an MA(1) model $x_t=c+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}$, what do you mean by *the model output*?

Comment: "Fitted values" may be the better term. It's what Eviews uses to plot its graph. How to compute those manually using only the estimated coefficients and the input series? @RichardHardy

Comment: Unlike AR models, I do not think you can do this in a straightforward way with an MA model.